# PHP copy files have spaces in the filename

Tags: php, copy

I can't find a way to copy a file with a space in filename with PHP. I tried replacing a space with `"\ "` but it doesn't work too.

> PHP Warning:
> copy(/home/user/images/Honeycomb
> Cotton\ Polo\ 1.jpg):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

Spaces should not be a problem. This might be a permission issue. Does PHP have permission to access the file?

Comment: What is the error message if you don't escape the spaces with a backslash?

Comment: Spaces is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Replace spaces with %20

```
$file_path = '/home/user/images/Honeycomb Cotton Polo 1.jpg';
$file_path = preg_replace('/\s/i', '%20', $file_path);

$new_path = '/home/user/images/Honeycomb-Cotton-Polo-1-copy.jpg';

copy($file_path, $new_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) check first:

```
$fileToCopy = '/home/user/images/Honeycomb Cotton Polo 1.jpg';
$target     = '/var/www/images/';

if (file_exists($fileToCopy)) {
    if (is_readable($fileToCopy)) {
         if (is_writeable(dirname($target))) {
             copy($fileToCopy, $target);
         } else {
             die('You dont have permission to write into '.dirname($target));
         }
    } else {
         die('You dont have permission to read '.$fileToCopy);
    }
} else {
    die('File '.$fileToCopy.' does not exist');
}
```

Comment: Checking if a file exists is a good thing, but it doesn't solve the problem of having a file which does exist and is not found regardless.

Comment: If it is not found, it does not exist in the path you are looking at!

Comment: No kidding. But IT DOESN'T answer the question. The OP tries to copy a file and it triggers a "file not found" error. Clearly the OP believes the file exists at that location. The question is "why is the file not found?". Adding file_exists() after you already received an error message saying that the file was not found is not helping answer the question. The only thing that's going to happen is that instead of receiving the original error message, the OP will now receive your custom error message telling him pretty much the same thing.

Comment: file_exists and copy relay on the same internal functionality. So if it is not found at the path you are looking at you pass the wrong path information.

Comment: @Powtac... yes, and we *already* know that for a fact, since we have the error message from copy(). So considering that this information is already available, what is the point of checking it again? The question could be rephrased as "why is the path wrong?", not "is the path wrong?"

Answer (score 0):

Replace spaces with %20

In your case :
copy(/home/user/images/Honeycomb\%20Cotton\%20Polo\%201.jpg)